# How to skip (problematic) Isabelle sessions in AFP?

Tags: isabelle

I tried to use AFP (02/22/2021) with Isabelle 2021, but the jEdit/Isabelle PIDE wouldn't load after the AFP directory is added to the user ROOT file. The is shown below and seems to be about a specific package:

[image]

I don't really need the entry in question (, or know what it does).
My question is:

Is there a way to use a subset of AFPs and exclude problematic entries in the screenshot?

-- Update ---

As pointed out in the comments, the AFP seemed to be lagging a couple of days behind. Using afp-02-24-2021, the initial error went away. However, when selecting a session `Jordan-Normal-Form` from jEdit, there is a new error about `JNF-AFP-Lib` build failing, as shown below:

[image]

The question remains. The AFP seems to be a large collection and there could be multiple sources of error.

*In case of such errors, is there a way to select a subset of AFPs to use or debug?*

If not, is there a systematic way to test which afps do or do not build?

Comment: Are you using the AFP-2021 distribution?

Comment: @larsrh, yes, I downloaded the afp-current the same time I downloaded Isabelle 2021.

Comment: AFP lags a few days behind, try downloading today's bundle. It might be the case that you caught AFP for 2020 still.

Comment: Yes, the error message above is definitely still AFP-2020. As Lars said, the AFP is always released a few days after Isabelle and AFP-2021 is now just out, so if you re-download it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Original question

The problem was because you (unknowingly) used an AFP release that did not match the Isabelle release. To avoid that problem in the future, I recommend using the Mercurial repository directly:

https://foss.heptapod.net/isa-afp/afp-2021

The Mercurial repository for a new Isabelle release gets created during the RC phase, so you can always be sure to have matching versions.

In the case of these mismatches, it is usually not possible to select a subset of the AFP that "works", because between 2020 and 2021, the session management has changed considerably.

### Update

The problem you're facing here is that you have selected a big session as a prerequisite and it takes too long to build with the default configuration.

You can build the session on the command line with an increased timeout as follows:

```
isabelle build -bv -d <path to afp>/thys -o timeout_scale=3 Jordan_Normal_Form
```

Increase the factor if it keeps timeouting.

### General remark

You ask, "In case of such errors, is there a way to select a subset of AFPs to use or debug?". The answer to that question depends on the kind of error. Your post currently contains two vastly different problems, so it's not possible to give a general answer, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks! The build command indeed works except that `-o time_factor` should be `-o timeout_scale` on my machine.